# Resultado de busca abrir em nova aba

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um motor de busca simples que faz a busca no próprio html, como posso fazer para que os resultados da busca sejam mostrados em uma nova aba?

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Digite sua pergunta"  autofocus name="query" size="16" style="font-size: 11 pt; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-; border: 1 solid #000000">
</font></font> <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"> 
<input  type="submit" value="Buscar" style="font-size: 8 pt; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-caps; border: 1 solid #000000">
```

Site de busca
http://leituracrista.com/indice/

Comment: Miguel só um detalhe, a tag `<font>` foi descuntinuada, vc deve fazer agora os estilos direto pelo CSS, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp além disso a tag de  fechamento `</font> ` está no lugar errado, deveria vir após `<font>`

Comment: Obrigado! @hugocsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode adicionar um atributo no  chamado "target",

ficaria assim:

```
<form action="" method="GET" target="_blank">
...
</form>
```

mais informações no link > https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

att,

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se te ajuda mas vc pode fazer assim:

Vc tem que bolar um jeito de pegar o que está digitado dentro do input `name="query"` e colocar no final do link `query=`

```
<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Buscar" style="">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://leituracrista.com/indice/?query=.....");
}
</script>
```

Sei que não é a reposta "completa" mas as vezes te ajuda. Com jQuery acredito que vc captura facilmente o valor do `input` de busca e coloca onde quiser. Mas não é muito minha área então não vou me estender.

Comment: Acredito que esse é o caminho, deste modo é possível por exemplo adicionar apenas o botão de busca em qualquer site, aguardo mais informações de outros

Comment: Preciso agora capturar o esse valor da query e jogar no final do endereço

Comment: Isso mesmo Miguel, acredito que não é algo complicado para que já domina JS, mas como não é meu caso só te dei um norte. Outros colaboradores do site com certeza vão te responder até melhor que eu.